# USB flash drive is not detected in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: linux, usb-flash-drive, ubuntu-12.04

I have 15GB Kingston flash drive. It is not detected in Ubuntu 12.04 and remains hung up in Windows too. `sudo fdisk -l` output:

> WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'!
>   The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.
>
> Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes 255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>   Disk identifier: 0x00000000
>
> Device Boot Start End Blocks Id System /dev/sda1 1 976773167 488386583+ ee GPT
>
> Disk /dev/sdb: 15.5 GB, 15479597056 bytes 64 heads, 32 sectors/track, 14762 cylinders, total 30233588 sectors Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>   Disk identifier: 0xe31d9cb0
>   Disk /dev/sdb doesn't contain a valid partition table

So, how to access my pendrive?

Comment: It seems to be your pendrive partition is corrupted or  USB stick is damaged and bad for use.Try formatting pendrive.

Comment: I tried formatting my drive using disk utility. It gives me following: Error creating filesystem with Details [Error creating file system: helper exited with exit code 1: Error calling fsync(2) on /dev/sdb: Input/output error]

Comment: Try using GParted instead